# Sophos UTM VPN not accessible

Tags: aws-cloudformation, vpn

I used the Sophos UTM 9.510 ha_standalone Cloudformation template (https://github.com/sophos-iaas/aws-cf-templates/blob/master/utm/9.510/standalone.template) and used defaults when possible. I did not use an existing ElasticIP, so it created it's own at (scrubbed) 50.12.12.123.

I gave a hostname at (for example) vpn.example.com and after creation, I created an A record for vpn.example.com to point to 50.12.12.123.

I don't have a license and just pay hourly for the AMI.

I understand that I should be able to hit https://vpn.example.com:4444 or https://50.12.12.123:4444 to see the admin panel. However, it times out and doesn't load anything.

When I deployed the stack, I got an email at the admin email I provided and it said `REST daemon not running - restarted`. I assume it restarted fine, since I have received no new emails, and the EC2 instance is running.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a step I'm missing? Aside from creating the Route53 record, I thought the Cloudformation Template should just work right out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default security groups blocked traffic. I modified one of them to accept all traffic and the dashboard became accessible. I will now refine access further.